# Validating UK phone number PHP

Tags: php, validation

Hi folks I have this condition. I want my phone number to only be valid if it's numbers or it is between 10 or 11 digits long?

```
if ((preg_match ('/^(01|02|03|08)/', $value) == 0) || ((strlen($value) != 10) && (strlen($value) != 11)) ) {
        $this->_error(self::INVALID);
        $isValid = false;
    }
```

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Which number is between 10 and 11 ?!

Comment: are you looking for a regexp?

Comment: Down-voted because after a quick Google search I found many, many answers. Lazy searcher.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `== 0` from your if, `preg_match` returns an empty string if false. Replace it with `if((!preg_match(...) || ...)`

Answer (score 2):

After a quick Google search, I found tons of answers. You really should do more research before asking.

This may help. It matches any numerical input 10-11 digits in length, like you asked.

```
$regex = "^([0-9]{10,11})$";
$input = $_POST['telephone_number']

if (preg_match($regex, $input)) {
    echo "Valid telephone number.";
} else {
    echo "Invalid telephone number.";
}
```

I would suggest sticking with that simple validation, as checking for every possible phone number format can be annoying. For example, a phone number `01424 730 234` could be inputted as:

```
01424730234
01424 730234
01424-730-234
01424 73 02 34
(01424) 730234
```

By looking at all the variations of one telephone number, validating it becomes a tough and daunting task. I would suggest removing all white-spaces, dashes, and brackets from the string, and then check that it's all numbers and 10-11 digits in length.

Something like this would remove anything non-numerical from a string before the validation takes place:

```
$regex = "^([0-9]{10,11})$";
$input = $_POST['telephone_number']

$cleaned_input = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $input); // leave only numbers

if (preg_match($regex, $cleaned_input)) {
    echo "Valid telephone number.";
} else {
    echo "Invalid telephone number.";
}
```